# Why is the word "Raubritter" (from German) used in English as the name of a rose?

Tags: meaning, etymology, germanic-languages

The German word "Raubritter" was used as an alias for a German knight with Robin Hood's style. Now it is used in English as a name of a rose. How did this come to be?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about English.

Comment: It's a literal translation of the phrase: Robber Baron. http://www.linguee.com/english-german/translation/robber+barons.html

Comment: Are we doing German etymology here now? Second vote to close.

Comment: I think the question is how got a rose in English a German word as name. I think that is a question for specialist of roses and their names.  Perhaps it was a German who developed that breed of rose.

Comment: @medica: the previous title was misleading in my opinion, and due to a later edit not by the OP, so I changed it – is the revised question still off topic? It seems to me to be about the origins of the use of the term in English.

Comment: The question is hardly off-topic.  It's about the use of a foreign word (or name) in English contexts.  Why was the name not Anglicized?

Comment: A robber baron is no Robin Hood.

Comment: How is this _not_ on topic for English? It's about a word used by English speaking people. It is somewhat arbitrary because it turns out to be someone's name, but the source language does not make it a non-English question.

Comment: Duh!!  Someone named the rose "Raubritter".  They might just as well picked "Gaspignugle", but they apparently preferred "Raubritter" and they had "naming rights".

Answer (score 1):

Raubritter seems to be the name of the person who developed the kind of roses called Raubritter:

http://www.classicroses.co.uk/products/gardenplants/macrantha-raubritter/

Comment: How does that link corroborate the statement above it? The page implies that someone called Kordes developed that rose in 1936.

Comment: You are right, it is not exactly clear what the name Macrantha Raubritter exactly is. That's why I wrote "seems to be".  If you want to have more information ask the company which sells the roses.

Comment: I did some research. In fact, *Raubritter* was the name Wilhelm Kordes chose, and is simply a varietal name. See [German Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raubritter_%28Rose%29). The question becomes one of why it wasn't Anglicised but the German word was retained.

Comment: A good find, the article Raubritter in German Wikipedia. I'm no specialist for the name of rose varieties. But is may be that the original names are not translated.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Are variety names of crossbed plants usually Anglicised? Are they not normally kept as they are? For instance, Åkerö, Alkmene, and Akane apples are not Anglicised to Akero, Alcmene, and Madder apples, so why should a Raubritter rose be called a Robber-Knight rose or anything like that in English?

Comment: @J That may well be the case, and if it is, then with the "name Kordes chose" bit it's the answer to the question.

Comment: @AndrewLeach we don't even Anglicise words like Autobahn, Zeitgeist, and Sprechstimme.  Why would we Anglicise a word that actually *is* a proper name?

Answer (score 1):

Because it's a [cultivar epithet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cultivar#Cultivar_names), which are generally international (and can therefore be used in English even when their source is another language). This was just the name chosen by the person who registered it; see the information on the "[Roses Database](http://allthingsplants.com/plants/view/1826/Rose-Rosa-Raubritter/)":

> Additional cultivar names:
>
> - 'Raubritter'
> - 'Rosa macrantha'Raubritter''
> - 'Macrantha Raubritter'

(In fact, Wikipedia suggests that the most correct form would actually be *Rosa macrantha* 'Raubritter'.)

---

> Hybridizer & year: Wilhelm J.H. Kordes II, 1936

As his name suggests, [Wilhelm J.H. Kordes II](http://www.helpmefind.com/rose/l.php?l=7.11537) was German. Many of the cultivars he bred had German names; you can see some of them on the Wikipedia article about the rose-breeding company that was run by him and his brother: [W. Kordes' Söhne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W._Kordes%27_S%C3%B6hne).

I have no idea why he chose this particular German word.